# Installing fglrx 13.3 with powerxpress on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

When trying to install fgrlx 13.3 from the AMD website, the installation goes smoothly, but when I  to aticonfig --initial -f, I get the following error:

```
    Uninitialised file found, configuring.
    PowerXpress info: Diagnostic output from /usr/lib64/fglrx/switchlibglx:
    update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
    update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules with a link
```

Then when I boot, X won't start.

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this? Is there a special installation procedure or version I should be using for 13.04 beta? I'm on xorg-edgers right now, but I could easily revert them.

My video card lines in lspci are as follows:

```
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [Radeon HD 6600M/6700M/7600M Series]
```

Comment: I think the aticonfig is the problem look at this link http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/03/new-ati-catalyst-12-3-has-been-released-how-to-install-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-linux-mint-12.html and pay attention to the second comment on this page - worked for me good luck

Comment: 13.4 is released have you tried it ?

Comment: Trying it now. At first, no luck, but I'll try the version in xorg edgers.

Comment: I get the same error when I do aticonfig --initial -f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BastiFantasti outlines a solution for 13.4 at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&page=76:

Basically, it requires getting older versions of the Intel drivers, and running

```
aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

after before rebooting.